# Change all file name and extension in directory in linux or windows

Tags: linux, windows, file-rename, file-management

I have thousands of file with file extensions like this

```
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai.html__201308050010_
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai.html__201308080012_
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai.html__201308100012_
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai.html__201308110034_ and so on.....
```

inside a directory. I wanna change all these into the following

```
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai__201308050010_.html
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai__201308080012_.html
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai__201308100012_.html
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai__201308110034_.html
```

When I tried doing it in windows using the following command

```
ren *.* *.html
```

I got the following

```
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found. and so on...
```

Because I know that it will try to change everything into a single file name like

```
3_bedroom_villas_in_chennai.html and so on...
```

any ways to do this either on windows or linux ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **Linux**:

```
ls | xargs -I % mv % %.html
```

`ls` command output is piped to `xargs`, and xargs replaces all % (after `mv`) with the input from `ls`

Also, if you want recursively go through all sub-directories, you might want to use:

```
find . -type f | xargs -I % mv % %.html
```

And in **Windows**:

```
for /r %x in (*) do ren "%x" *.txt
```

Comment: It worked .. thanks:) May I know how to do the same in windows?

Comment: @Venky I added a windows solution. (Tested in Windows 7)

Comment: @julumme can you please explain what each part of `ls | xargs -I % mv % %.html` does? I mean why is `-I` used?

Comment: Also, what if I want to rename a specific extension?

Comment: @Ranveer, the `-I` defines the string to be replaced. In this example I used `%`-sign. It does not have to be a single character, but usually it's easier to understand what is going on. So it means that xargs will replace all further occurrences of `%` signs for the input from `ls` (or `find`) command. So for example `echo 1 | xargs -I % echo %%%` will print `111` to the console

Answer (score 1):

using [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer):

```
$ renamer --regex --find '(.*).html(.*)' --replace '$1$2.html' *
```

Works on Windows, Mac and Linux.